# Netsuite Custom Print Templates: Why are my negative numbers are coming in with a trailing symbol (100- instead of -100)

Tags: netsuite, suitescript, suitescript2.0, freemarker

Netsuite Custom Print Templates: My negative numbers are coming in with a trailing symbol (100- instead of -100)

It is a custom print from a ftl file in the fileCabinet. It is very weird and I can't seem to figure out if it has to do with the NS environment setup or maybe I should be doing something in the FLT file to fix it? I was able to find a reference to this in the NS documentation - [link](https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/saas/netsuite/ns-online-help/section_N742001.html) -  but it is not regarding a print its regarding reports.

HELP PLEASE -_-

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try these in the template to at least know what setting causes this:

- `<#setting locale="en_US">`
- `<#setting number_format="0.####">`

If neither, then it's certainly an RTL issue. In languages where you write right-to-left (RTL), Arabic numbers are still written left-to-right, but in some the sign stays on the right side. So 100- is how it should look, in some language. But this rearrangement is not in the raw text, it's how for example a browser renders the text.